# Java Cannot resolve method 'getEntity' in 'HttpResponse'

Tags: java, api

So these are the imports that I use:

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.hc.core5.net.URIBuilder;
import java.net.URI;
```

And this is code that I made:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'getEntity' in 'HttpResponse'
```

I tried looking for solutions, but they were all for Android. I am using Java, and I use IntelliJ

This code comes from this sample:

```
    // // This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org   /httpcomponents-client-ga/)

public class JavaSample 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

     try
     {
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://gateway.apiportal.ns.nl/reisinformatie-api/api/v2/departures");

        builder.setParameter("station", "{string}");
        builder.setParameter("uicCode", "{string}");
        builder.setParameter("dateTime", "{integer}");
        builder.setParameter("lang", "nl");
        builder.setParameter("maxJourneys", "{integer}");

        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");


        // Request body
        StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{body}");
        request.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the sample is for HttpClient 4.5 and you are using 5.0. Here are some examples: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/examples.html

Answer (score 5):

This solved the problem:

```
ClassicHttpResponse response = (ClassicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```